# Bug visual usando LongListSelector (grouped) e Checkbox Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que possui uma lista agrupada, e dentro de cada item da lista existe um checkbox. O problema que vem ocorrendo acontece quando o checkbox do primeiro item do grupo 1 é selecionado, o checkbox do primeiro item do grupo 2 também é selecionado. Mas isso só ocorre visualmente, em nenhum momento o evento de check é chamado para o 2 checkbox. Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso, e se sim como fazer para resolver, obrigado.

EDIT: ----

No meu xml tenho o LongListSelector:

```
<phone:LongListSelector 
                x:Name="llsAlunosTurmas"
                Background="Transparent"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AddrBookItemTemplate}"
                LayoutMode="List" />
```

e o data template dos itens:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AddrBookItemTemplate" x:Name="dte" >
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Margin="0,3,0,0" 
                    Background="White"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" 
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource CorTxtPagina}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Text="{Binding matricula}"
                           Width="385"
                           FontSize="16"
                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" 
                           FontStretch="SemiCondensed"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="{StaticResource CorTxtPagina}" 
                           Text="{Binding nomAlu}" 
                           Width="385"
                           FontSize="16"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                </StackPanel>
                <CheckBox x:Name="cbxAlunos"
                      Background="{StaticResource CorBotoes}" 
                      Click="cbxAlunos_Click"
                      IsChecked="{Binding selecionado, Mode=OneWay}"
                      Tag="{Binding idtAlu}"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

e no c#, depois de receber os dados por webservice, organizo como os dados serão exibidos(o agrupamento) e coloco como dataset da lista:

```
 if (lista.Count != 0)
        {
            int cont = 0;

            string turmaAtual = lista.First().idtTurma;
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                if (turmaAtual != item.idtTurma)
                {
                    cont++;
                    turmaAtual = item.idtTurma;
                }
                item.ordem = cont + "";
            }
            List<string> headers = lista.GroupBy(aluno => aluno.idtTurma).Select(grp => grp.First().turma).ToList();

            lista = lista.OrderBy(aluno => aluno.nomAlu).ToList();
            alunos = lista;

            llsAlunosTurmas.ItemsSource = AlphaKeyGroup<Aluno>.CreateGroups(lista, headers,
                                            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
                                            (Aluno a) => { return a.ordem; }, false);
        }
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverFlow Português Kelvin. Seria interessante vc postar seu código e mostrar nele onde pode ser a possível causa do bug, desta forma fica melhor para a comunidade ajudar vc.

Comment: Olá dener, obrigado por responder, já adicionei o código como mencionado. Abr.